# Using binding inside SQL procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble getting the following code to work:

```
create or replace secure procedure create_wh (wh_name varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
comment = '<string_literal>'
execute as owner
as
begin
    create warehouse if not exists :wh_name
    warehouse_size = xsmall
    auto_suspend = 60
    auto_resume = true
    initially_suspended = true;
    return 'SUCCES';
end;
```

The idea is that the SP can be called with a name for a warehouse. It errors in `unexpected 'if'` after the create warehouse statement when trying to run the above code.

I am guessing I am missing something in relation to binding the param to the query, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide warehouse name as parameter by using `IDENTIFIER(:wh_name)`:

```
create or replace secure procedure create_wh (wh_name varchar)
returns varchar
language sql
comment = '<string_literal>'
execute as owner
as
begin
    create warehouse if not exists IDENTIFIER(:wh_name)
      warehouse_size = xsmall
      auto_suspend = 60
      auto_resume = true
      initially_suspended = true;

    return 'SUCCES';
end;

CALL create_wh('test');

SHOW WAREHOUSES;
```